# How to create array of ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays

for my program I need to create an array of ArrayLists.

Is this even possible?

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
public static ArrayList<Chemical> [] [] chemicals;
chemicals = new ArrayList<Chemical>[cols][rows];
```

It gives a generic array creation error.

Thank you.

Comment: @pickypg Not really a duplicate - the issue there is trying to use a primitive with generics.

Comment: @Dukeling Yeah, I noticed it was `int` rather than `Integer` after marking it, but the similarity still exists even though I prefer yours.

Comment: You can use `List Within list` to overcome the problem of to defining row and column at coding time like List<List<Chemical>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Chemical>>();

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work in Java 8

```
ArrayList<Chemical>[][] chemicals = new ArrayList[cols][rows];
```

Comment: It works in Java 7 and Java 6 too

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
public static ArrayList<Chemical> [] [] chemicals;
chemicals  = new ArrayList[cols][rows];
```

and put @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") on the class

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following ways :

**1.**

```
List<List<Chemical>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<List<Chemical>>();
```

or other way :

**2.**

It may be more appropriate to use a `Map<Chemical, List<Chemical>>`. Having the value of the Map as a `List<Chemical>` will allow you to expand the list as opposed to an array which has a fixed size.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Map<Chemical, List<Chemical>> myMap = create(1, 3);
}

public static Map<Chemical, List<Chemical>> create(double row, double column) {
    Map<Chemical, List<Chemical>> chemicalMap = new HashMap<Chemical, List<Chemical>>();

    for (double x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        for (double y = 0; y < column; y++) {
            chemicalMap.put(x, new ArrayList<Chemical>());
        }
    }
    return chemicalMap;
}
```